# dictionary comprehension for counting items in the list doesn't work. but normal version works

Tags: python, dictionary, split, count, dictionary-comprehension

### Edit 2:

thanks to the guidance of [@john-gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon), I found the problem.

I was searching through a wrong list. which i fixed by changing the first case to

```
splitted_subs = [] #> a list that will be used for splitting the values before searching in them.
                
for sub in self.subList: # Splitting the subtitles
    splitted_subs.append(sub.rsplit(".",1)[-1])
    
subtitle_counter = {sub.rsplit(".",1)[-1]: splitted_subs.count(sub.rsplit(".",1)[-1]) for sub in self.subList}
```

---

I'm trying to count the "type of subtitle" I have in a folder.

**how it works**

- it takes the `subtitle_list` and stores it in `self.subList`
- then there is a for loop which loops `for sub in self.subList`
- in the loop the `sub` gets `rsplit(".",1)`-ed and then will be the key of the dictionary while the `self.subList.count(sub)` will counts the occurance of the subtitle extension. like `{srt : 2}`

and there is a strange problem during the splitting phase of subtitle's file name for extracting its file extension.

the below code only works if `countType = Multi-line_2` and the two other cases don't work.

```
subtitle_list = ['10_Dutch.srt', '11_Spanish.idx', '12_Finnish.sub', '13_French.srt','4_English.idx','5_French.sub']

countType = "Multi-line_2"

class MovieSub:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subList = subtitle_list
        
    def subtitle_counter(self):
        
        match countType:
            case "oneLiner":
                #> One-liner way of counting the different types of subtitles in subList which somehow doesn't work !!! (no it's not because of the self reference of subList., it's because of the split but which part i don't know.)
                subtitle_counter = {sub.rsplit(".",1)[-1]: self.subList.count(sub.rsplit(".",1)[-1]) for sub in self.subList}
            
            case "Multi-line_1":
                
                subtitle_counter = {}
                splitted_subs = []
                for sub in self.subList:
                    splitted_subs.append(sub)

                
                for sub in splitted_subs:
                    splitted_sub = sub.rsplit(".",1)[-1]
                    subtitle_counter[splitted_sub] = splitted_subs.count(splitted_sub)
                
            case "Multi-line_2":
                
                subtitle_counter = {}
                splitted_subs = []
                
                for sub in self.subList: # Splitting the subtitles
                    splitted_subs.append(sub.rsplit(".",1)[-1])
                    # print(sub.rsplit(".",1)[-1])
                
                for sub in splitted_subs: # Counting the Splitted Subtitles
                    subtitle_counter[sub] = splitted_subs.count(sub)

        print(subtitle_counter)
        #> the multi-line version of the code (lame version)
        
        
movie = MovieSub()

movie.subtitle_counter()
```

the result of `"Multi-line_1"` and `"oneLiner"` cases:

```
>> {'srt': 0, 'idx': 0, 'sub': 0}
```

result of `"Multi-line_2"` Case:

```
>> {'srt': 2, 'idx': 2, 'sub': 2}
```

I tried to understand how it's possible and only found that it's a problem when I split the file name in the same scope which i count them (`Multi-line_2` case), I don't know if it's relevent to the problem or not.

I will be thankful if anyone could help me out about what I'm missing.

### edit 1 :

I think there is a need for an explanation
first of all, my variable names are a bit misleading and `splitted_subs` and `splitted_sub` are different variables.

second: the story of this match case system is that my first case which is a dictionary comprehension didn't work, so I tried to debug it by expanding the code which is `Multi-line_1` case, then it didn't work again and I changed the position of split to before appending to the list and its the `Multi-line_2` case, and I understood the problem was with the placement of my split method. but why? that's my question

so if you add a print statement before the final line of `Multi-line_1` like below:

```
print(splitted_sub)
subtitle_counter[splitted_sub] = splitted_subs.count(splitted_sub)
```

and another before final line of `Multi-line_2` like:

```
print(sub)
subtitle_counter[sub] = splitted_subs.count(sub)
```

they will print the same input but not the same results.

`Multi-line_1` results:

```
>> srt
>> idx
>> sub
>> srt
>> idx
>> sub
>> {'srt': 0, 'idx': 0, 'sub': 0}
```

`Multi-line_2` results:

```
>> srt
>> idx
>> sub
>> srt
>> idx
>> sub
>> {'srt': 2, 'idx': 2, 'sub': 2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case "Multi-line_1":
            
    subtitle_counter = {}
    splitted_subs = []
    for sub in self.subList:
        splitted_subs.append(sub)
            
    for sub in splitted_subs:
        splitted_sub = sub.rsplit(".",1)[-1]
        subtitle_counter[splitted_sub] = splitted_subs.count(splitted_sub)
```

`splitted_sub` is just the file extension, i.e. ".srt".

But the items in `splitted_subs` are the full filename, i.e. "10_Dutch.srt".  (The variable name is misleading -- those values are *not* split.)

So of course `.count()` returns zero.

Comment: first of all, you're right the variable names are misleading (couldn't think of a different Name), but as you can see `splitted_sub` in `Multi-line_1` and `sub` in `Multi-line_2`, are the same variable and placed the same way.

the only difference I can see is `splitted_sub` is rsplitted in the same scope
and `sub` is rsplitted in another scope (the for loop before)

I'm sorry if I'm confused and don't see your point.

Comment: `splitted_subs` is different in the two cases.  In the multiline_1 case, `splitted_subs` is a direct copy of `subtitle_list`, containing full filenames.  But in the multiline_2 case, `splitted_subs` contains only the file extensions.

Comment: Some very basic debugging, just printing out all the variables as you're using them, would have revealed the issue.  Did you really not think of doing that?

Comment: you're absolutely right, but I intended to split the subtitle names in two scenarios, once before appending it to the list and once after appending it to the list and during the final loop. 

In `Multi-line_1` the name is splitted in the final for loop and used as both key of the dictionary and `.count()` parameter.

In `Multi-line_2` however, it's splitted just before appending to the  `splitted_subs`.
so in the end, the final line for both  `Multi-line_1` and  `Multi-line_2` have the same inputs with different Variable names. or at least this is what I can understand.

Comment: The inputs are _not_ the same.  `splitted_subs` contains different values in the two cases, and so the `splitted_subs.count(...)` call is counting _different things_ in the two cases.

Comment: All you have to do is print the value of `splitted_subs` in both cases, and it will be obvious.

Comment: just printed out this: `print(splitted_sub)` just before `subtitle_counter[splitted_sub]`. result: srt idx sub srt idx sub {'srt': 0, 'idx': 0, 'sub': 0};

`print(sub)` just before `subtitle_counter[sub]`. result: srt 
idx 
sub 
srt 
idx 
sub 
{'srt': 2, 'idx': 2, 'sub': 2}; I don't see a difference In input, I see differences in results.
that's my problem.

Comment: You're refusing to follow my advice, so I'm going to stop helping.  Good luck.

Comment: of course between the loops they are different, in `Multi-line_1` split happens before appending to the list and in the  `Multi-line_2` it happens after appending to the loop and before using as key and count parameter.

Comment: look I'm just explaining the logic behind what I intended to do, my first case which is a dictionary comprehension doesn't work, so I tried to debug it by expanding the code which is  `Multi-line_1` case, then it didn't work again and I changed the position of split to before appending to the list and it's case  `Multi-line_2`.please don't get offended. I just don't understand what you're trying to say. I tried everything you said and you're answers are different from solution to my problem

Comment: I'm sorry, as I said before, I was confused and couldn't understand what you are saying
I thought the problem is from my single_subtitle variables, but as you mentioned, my problem was the list I was searching. 
I fixed it and case one is working as well.
thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.